# Subjunctive or not

Tags: syntactic-analysis

A citation from the movie *Thor* :

> *I'll only be in the way, or worse, get one of you killed?*

What is the construction "get one of you killed"?
Is it present subjunctive?
Does it have anything in common with "be but sworn my love" from Shakespeare?

Comment: Neither of those is the subjunctive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'll only be in the way, or worse, get one of you killed.

It is easy to see why someone might be puzzled about the phrase *get one of you killed*. The verb *get* is in the plain form here, as it would be if it were in a subjunctive. The sentence is complicated by the parenthetical word *worse*. This word does not change the meaning of the sentence, and it is not integrated into the syntax. We could put it in brackets or between dashes or commas:

- I'll only be in the way, or— worse—get  one of you killed.

If we remove it the sentence should become clearer:

- I'll only be in the way, or get one of you killed.

The auxiliary verb *WILL* is followed by  a verb phrase using a verb in the plain form. Here it is followed by a coordination of two such verb phrases joined by the coordinator *or*:

- I will [be in the way] or [get one of you killed].

Notice that we could change the order of the coordinates:

- I will [get one of you killed] or [be in  the way].

The reason then that the verb *get* looks a bit like a subjunctive is because it is a plain form of the verb. However, it is just in the plain form because of the auxiliary verb *will*.

Comment: I thought I'd be able to parse "Both infinitives" in the last sentence once it stood on its own, but now I'm not so sure.

Comment: @deadrat No, that was en editing stuff up on my part. Thanks for the edit!

Comment: De nada.  By the way, what reference do you recommend for English grammar?

Comment: Isn't it an ELL question? I think it would be better if we could migrate it first and answer there. What is your opinion?

Comment: @deadrat I'd recommend [A Student's Introduction to English Grammar](http://www.abebooks.co.uk/9780521848374/Students-Introduction-English-Grammar-Huddleston-0521848377/plp) Huddleston & Pullum 2002. Then if I need more detail I normally refer to [CaGEL](https://ia800504.us.archive.org/16/items/TheCambridgeGrammarOfTheEnglishLanguage/The%20Cambridge%20grammar%20of%20the%20English%20language.pdf#page=03&zoom=auto,-242,851). The latter costs an arm and a leg. But you can read the pdf in that link I gave.

Comment: @deadrat  You can read the SIEG [here](http://www.slideshare.net/MrMinhajahmed/a-students-introduction-to-english-grammar). I also recommend [*Oxford Modern English Grammar*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Oxford-Modern-English-Grammar-Bas-Aarts/dp/0199533199), Bas Aarts. He was my prof when I was studying syntax.

Comment: @Rathony Might be a good idea, I concur. I just whipped of an answer, because I had ten minutes spare and can't do any long ones at the moment (like your prepositions question!)

Comment: No worry about the NOW question. NOW I understand.  I am thinking about posting another question on **prepositions** OVER, THERE and HERE. The thing is migration doesn't seem to work very well. That's what I felt. (Primarily-Opinion-Based)